# Numpy equivalent of if/else list comprehension

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a numpy way of doing

```
n = [x-t if x > 0 else x for x in nps]
```

similar to this

```
n = np.array(a)
n[np.abs(n) < t] = 0
```

something like this perhaps?

```
n[n > 0] = n-t
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Can't test now, but try

```
np.where(n > 0, n - t, n)
```

See [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)